# Looking for a suitable lubricant

Tags: windshield-wipers, lubrication

I'm rebuilding a Lucas windshield wiper motor.  It's pretty old and the manual recommends using Ragosine Listate grease for the gear and connecting rod and Shell Turbo 41 for the bearings.  Neither is available anymore but after a lot of internet research, I've found that the modern versions would meet these military specs:

- Ragosine:  NATO G-382, British DEF STAN 91-12/1, or US [MIL-DTL-23549](http://everyspec.com/MIL-SPECS/MIL-SPECS-MIL-DTL/download.php?spec=MIL-DTL-23549D.029090.pdf)
- Shell:  NATO O-240, British [DEFSTAN 91-25/3:1997](ftp://ftp.iks-jena.de/mitarb/lutz/standards/dstan/91/025/00000400.pdf) (no US MIL equivalent)

I've found these standards online and lots of companies that claim to meet them.  But I don't understand the technical details well enough to be able to find a consumer/over-the-counter version that I can buy locally (in the US).

Can anybody recommend some or translate these standards into plain English?

Comment: To clear up some confusion: is this motor for a car or an airplane?

Comment: And do you insist on fluids that are certified to meet the military specifications you mention, or are you just looking for a recommendation for fluids that would be generally suitable for this kind of an application?

Comment: This is for a car and I'm only looking for a rec. that would be generally suitable.  I mentioned the miltary standards because I don't know how else to describe these lubricants (other than by their obsolete names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't the only one to have this problem...

According to what I'm reading the Ragosine grease was probably discontinued because they contained lead at some point. They still make greases to that MIL spec though, so *check out ROYCO 49 as a substitute for the Ragosine Listate*. I'm referencing this site and your spec: http://www.classicroverforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=17105

..and according to this website you can use *Shell Turbo 68 to replace the Turbo 41* http://www.lubebase.com/cgi-bin/ctl/lube/Petro-Canada-TURBOFLO-R-O-68?id=8756

Now since you only need a little bit I would call a local oil & lube supplier to see if they can get you tubes or agree to buy the bucket in return for your spreading the word and sending people their way. Just a thought.

Sorry though, I can't tell recommend what to buy off the shelf but hopefully this helps put you in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

Try and see if you can get hold of Castrol waterpump grease and use that instead

Comment: Can you give any reference as to *why* you'd suggest using this grease? Does it match the specs given? If so, can you show us where those specs can be found? Since there are two different specs, how does that equate to the single grease you have listed? Also, remember, this is an aircraft parts, so specifications are there for a purpose.

Comment: @Paulster: This is an aircraft part? How do you deduce that?

Comment: @NateEldredge - If you go into the specs listed, they are both specified for aircraft.

Comment: @Paulster: I assumed they were just general purpose grease products that happen to also be used for military airplanes. I haven't found any reference to Lucas making wiper motors for aircraft, only cars. Anyway I asked the OP to clarify.